# Spring Boot consuming Rest null-values

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'd like to consume the Rest Api from FishBase with Spring Boot:

https://fishbase.ropensci.org/sealifebase/comnames?limit=1&offset=0

I use the following classes:

InComnames

```
package com.example.demo.Model.input;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
public class InComnames {

    @Id
    private int autoctr;
    private String ComName;
    private String Transliteration;
    private int StockCode;
    private int SpecCode;
    private String C_Code;
    private String Language;
    private String Script;
    private String UnicodeText;
    private String NameType;
    private int PreferredName;
    private int TradeName;
    private int TradeNameRef;
    private int ComNamesRefNo;
    private int Misspelling;
    private String Size;
    private String Sex;
    private String Language2;
    private String Locality2;
    private int Rank;
    private String Remarks;
    private String SecondWord;
    private String ThirdWord;
    private String FourthWord;
    private int Entered;
    private String DateEntered;
    private int Modified;
    private String DateModified;
    private int Expert;
    private String DateChecked;
    private String Core;
    private String modifier1;
    private String modifier2;
    private int CLOFFSCA;
    private String E_Append;
    private String E_DateAppend;
    private String TS;

    public InComnames() {
    }

//Getter and Setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InComnames{" +
                "autoctr=" + autoctr +
                ", ComName='" + ComName + '\'' +
                ", Transliteration='" + Transliteration + '\'' +
                ", StockCode=" + StockCode +
                ", SpecCode=" + SpecCode +
                ", C_Code='" + C_Code + '\'' +
                ", Language='" + Language + '\'' +
                ", Script='" + Script + '\'' +
                ", UnicodeText='" + UnicodeText + '\'' +
                ", NameType='" + NameType + '\'' +
                ", PreferredName=" + PreferredName +
                ", TradeName=" + TradeName +
                ", TradeNameRef=" + TradeNameRef +
                ", ComNamesRefNo=" + ComNamesRefNo +
                ", Misspelling=" + Misspelling +
                ", Size='" + Size + '\'' +
                ", Sex='" + Sex + '\'' +
                ", Language2='" + Language2 + '\'' +
                ", Locality2='" + Locality2 + '\'' +
                ", Rank=" + Rank +
                ", Remarks='" + Remarks + '\'' +
                ", SecondWord='" + SecondWord + '\'' +
                ", ThirdWord='" + ThirdWord + '\'' +
                ", FourthWord='" + FourthWord + '\'' +
                ", Entered=" + Entered +
                ", DateEntered='" + DateEntered + '\'' +
                ", Modified=" + Modified +
                ", DateModified='" + DateModified + '\'' +
                ", Expert=" + Expert +
                ", DateChecked='" + DateChecked + '\'' +
                ", Core='" + Core + '\'' +
                ", modifier1='" + modifier1 + '\'' +
                ", modifier2='" + modifier2 + '\'' +
                ", CLOFFSCA=" + CLOFFSCA +
                ", E_Append='" + E_Append + '\'' +
                ", E_DateAppend='" + E_DateAppend + '\'' +
                ", TS='" + TS + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Quote

```
package com.example.demo.Model;

import com.example.demo.Model.input.InComnames;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Quote {

    private int count;
    private int returned;
    private List<InComnames> data;
    private String error;

    public Quote() {
    }

//Getter and Setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Quote{" +
                "count=" + count +
                ", returned=" + returned +
                ", data=" + data +
                ", error='" + error + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

DemoApplication

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.Model.Quote;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject(
                    "https://fishbase.ropensci.org/sealifebase/comnames?limit=1&offset=0", Quote.class);

            System.out.println(quote.toString());
        };
    }
}
```

My Result is :

```
Quote{count=31138, returned=1, data=[InComnames{autoctr=40545, ComName='null', Transliteration='null', StockCode=0, SpecCode=0, C_Code='null', Language='null', Script='null', UnicodeText='null', NameType='null', PreferredName=0, TradeName=0, TradeNameRef=0, ComNamesRefNo=0, Misspelling=0, Size='null', Sex='null', Language2='null', Locality2='null', Rank=0, Remarks='null', SecondWord='null', ThirdWord='null', FourthWord='null', Entered=0, DateEntered='null', Modified=0, DateModified='null', Expert=0, DateChecked='null', Core='null', modifier1='null', modifier2='null', CLOFFSCA=0, E_Append='null', E_DateAppend='null', TS='null'}], error='null'}
```

The inner JSON-Object "data" have only NULL-VALUES. Why?

Comment: My first guess would be incorrectly defined setters. Try to make `ComName` public and lowerCase, like `comName`, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@JsonProperty` to force right property spelling.

For instance if you have getter like `getConName` - then expected JSON field is `conName`... To check - please try:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
public class InComnames {

    @Id
    private int autoctr;
    @JsonProperty("ConName")
    private String ComName;
```

If that is OK - fix other fields.